# Not able to display gif from local uri using glide

Tags: android, gif, local-files

Thanks in advance,

I am trying to show a gif image in my imageView . Gif image exists locally in my device.

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    File file = new File(Environment
          .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "sample.gif");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

The file path is correct, still not able to see the gif loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using gif image from raw folder than please use below code

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.sample_gif).into(imageViewTarget);
```

If you are using any other url for loading gif image.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

Keep in mind that just using load() will load either a GIF or a Bitmap depending on the type of the data. Unless you want your load to fail if the given url is not a gif, you don't need to specify asGif()..

Hope this help u...inform me if u need any other help